# Which chapter of the manga does Season 1 of Nanatsu no Taizai: Mokushiroku no Yonkishi anime end in?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

If I want to keep following Nanatsu no Taizai: Mokushiroku no Yonkishi story in the manga, after the first season of the anime ended, which chapter of the manga the anime do I have to read?

Which chapter of the manga does Season 1 of Nanatsu no Taizai: Mokushiroku no Yonkishi anime end in?